# urllib: html to csv error

Tags: python, pandas, urllib

I tried to grab tabular data and save as csv file as follows:

```
import urllib, pandas as pd
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-JPY/history?period1=1314403200&period2=1314489600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'

fo = 'test.txt'                

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html =  response.read()
data = pd.read_html(html)
data.to_csv(fo, index = False, header=False, sep=',', mode='w')
```

but got following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U95') dtype('<U95') dtype('<U95')
```

without pandas

```
lines = html.splitlines()
for l in lines:
    fo.write(str(l) + '\n')
```

it writes bytes, unreadable format .

i just need tabular data

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close*  Adj Close** Volume
Aug 28, 2011    700.99  700.99  700.99  700.99  700.99  -
Aug 27, 2011    700.99  700.99  700.99  700.99  700.99  700
```

Comment: At the page, you can see alternative download link with well-formated csv: `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BTC-JPY?period1=1314403200&period2=1314489600&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=ppzh5XkBJcy`

Comment: nope, i want pythonic access

Comment: Pandas read_html magic may not be strong enough if the page is complex with blocks loaded via javascript for example. If you cannot understand the downloaded page, why should pandas be able to?

Comment: Load this `csv` with `urllib` and put it into `pandas`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes so, also tried without python, but it's complex

Comment: Another solution - using [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You need to find and parse table with attribute `data-test="historical-prices"`.

Comment: Agreed with @StanislavIvanov use beautifulsoup, requests or selenium to parse the data.

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`
`table = soup.select_one("historical-prices")`
`print (table)`

Comment: `print (table)` `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will produce what u are looking for :

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import html5lib
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-JPY/history?period1=1314403200&period2=1314489600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'

fo = 'test.txt'
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html =  response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table")
headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]
file = open(fo,"w")
file.write(",".join(headings) + "\n")
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    data = [td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")]
    if len(data)==len(headings):
        file.write(",".join(data) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Output:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close*,Adj Close**,Volume
Aug 28, 2011,700.99,700.99,700.99,700.99,700.99,-
Aug 27, 2011,700.99,700.99,700.99,700.99,700.99,700
```

Comment: i do not need `*Close price adjusted for splits.**Adjusted close price adjusted for both dividends and splits.`

Comment: how to remove that?

Comment: Udpated the code to prodcue output exactly as you wanted

Comment: @SergeBallesta okay, i used `data = data[:-1]`

Comment: that will only remove the last element value i.e volume form your final output.

Comment: yes, thanks. could you tell me alternative way to remove that last unwanted row? because i have not used header